# How to edit the user's roles on modal submit?

Tags: discord, discord.py, captcha

Well I've tried a lot of things to fix this, but nothing worked.

(please excuse my English, I'm French and I do my best ^^)

Here is the whole code of my command:

```py
#captchamodal
class Captcha(discord.ui.Modal, title="Formulaire de Verification"):
    captresult = discord.ui.TextInput(label="code du Captcha", placeholder=f"code = {captrand}", max_length=6, min_length=6)
    

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if captrand == self.captresult:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"le Captcha a bien été validé {interaction.user.display_name} !", ephemeral=True)
            role = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.role, id=1115589231474122783) #the errors come from this line, and the 2 following
            await interaction.user.edit(nick=f"{interaction.user.display_name}")
            await interaction.user.add_roles(role)

class CaptchaButton(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    @discord.ui.button(label="Captcha", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji="<Roger:1117098522936881162>")
    async def on_click(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(Captcha())

@tree.command(name = "captcha", description = "[MODERATION] génère un captcha.", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def CaptchaEmbed(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    emb=discord.Embed(title="Code à usage unique", description=f"{interaction.user.display_name}, intéragis avec le bouton ci-dessous pour remplir le captcha avec un code :\r\n", color = discord_blue, timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
    emb.set_author(name="BreadBot", url="https://discordapp.com/users/793183664858071040", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/1102573935658283038/f769161ee8e6a63563b1166ab7c016b5.webp?size=128")
    emb.set_thumbnail(url=f"{interaction.user.avatar}") # type: ignore
    emb.set_footer(text=f"{interaction.guild.name}", icon_url=interaction.guild.icon) # type: ignore 
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=emb, view=CaptchaButton(), ephemeral=True)
```

I get these errors:

```
Cannot access member "role" for type "Guild"
Member "role" is unknown
"role" is not a known member of "None"
```

```
Cannot access member "edit" for type "User"
Member "edit" is unknown
```

```
Cannot access member "add_roles" for type "User"
Member "add_roles" is unknown
```

I tried to replace user with member, but it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

The first error, on line `role = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild...`, is because `discord.utils.get()` expects an iterable.

The line should be `discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, id=1115589231474122783)` instead.

Also added a bonus fix on the `guild.icon` in the footer, to support guilds without icons, as my test server did not have one.

Here's the new code:

```py
class Captcha(discord.ui.Modal, title="Formulaire de Verification"):
    captrand = random.randint(100000, 999999)
    captresult = discord.ui.TextInput(label="code du Captcha", placeholder=f"code = {captrand}", max_length=6, min_length=6)

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if int(self.captresult.value) == self.captrand:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"le Captcha a bien été validé {interaction.user.display_name}!", ephemeral=True)
            role = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, id=1115589231474122783)
            await interaction.user.edit(nick=f"{interaction.user.display_name}")
            await interaction.user.add_roles(role)


class CaptchaButton(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @discord.ui.button(label="Captcha", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji="<Roger:1117098522936881162>")
    async def on_click(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
      await interaction.response.send_modal(Captcha())


# App / Slash Command
@tree.command(name="captcha", description="[MODERATION] génère un captcha.", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def CaptchaEmbed(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    emb=discord.Embed(title="Code à usage unique", description=f"{interaction.user.display_name}, intéragis avec le bouton ci-dessous pour remplir le captcha avec un code :\r\n", color = discord.Colour.blue(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
    emb.set_author(name="BreadBot", url="https://discordapp.com/users/793183664858071040", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/1102573935658283038/f769161ee8e6a63563b1166ab7c016b5.webp?size=128")
    emb.set_thumbnail(url=interaction.user.avatar.url)
    emb.set_footer(text=interaction.guild.name, icon_url=None if ctx.guild.icon == None else ctx.guild.icon.url)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=emb, view=CaptchaButton(), ephemeral=True)


# Prefixed Command
@commands.guild_only() # Optional but useful, as the command is designed to exclusively work in guilds
@client.command(name="captcha")
async def CaptchaEmbed(ctx):
    emb=discord.Embed(title="Code à usage unique", description=f"{ctx.author.display_name}, intéragis avec le bouton ci-dessous pour remplir le captcha avec un code :\r\n", color = discord.Colour.blue(), timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
    emb.set_author(name="BreadBot", url="https://discordapp.com/users/793183664858071040", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/1102573935658283038/f769161ee8e6a63563b1166ab7c016b5.webp?size=128")
    emb.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar)
    emb.set_footer(text=ctx.guild.name, icon_url=None if ctx.guild.icon == None else ctx.guild.icon)
    await ctx.send(embed=emb, view=CaptchaButton(), ephemeral=True)
```